# Output a Uint8ClampedArray buffer as a stream of bytes

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, arraybuffer

In a PhantomJS script, I have a `Uint8ClampedArray` (image data from a HTML canvas) that I would like to output to stdout as a byte stream.

In Node.js I would do:

```
buf = new Buffer(...);
process.stdout.write(buf);
```

How would I go about doing the same thing in PhantomJS?

I can't just output `String.fromCharCode()` for each of my bytes, as for example `String.fromCharCode(255)` outputs two bytes, not one (i.e. any byte between 128 and 255 will output two bytes).

Comment: I think so. Does it produce strange results when you do?

Comment: Not really. I'm just really not sure that it's idiomatic or elegant to do this.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Improved my question with the fact that bytes above 0x7f will output to two different bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to write to stdout using the `fs` phantomjs module, thus being able to write as binary:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.open('/dev/stdout', 'wb');
stream.write(String.fromCharCode(128));
stream.flush();
```

It is still pretty slow for large volume of data, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The only sane way of printing to the console is using `console.log()`. The drawback is that it inserts a newline everytime you call it, so you can't just print every character separately. You have to build a string and print it afterwards. As you noted, you can convert every byte to char with `String.fromCharCode()`.

Also, functions like [`Uint8ClampedArray.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/join) are not yet implemented.

```
var a = new Uint8ClampedArray([37, 38, 39]);
console.log([].map.call(a, function(v){
    return String.fromCharCode(v);
}).join());
```

Note that `Uint8ClampedArray` is not available in PhantomJS 1.x.

`console.log()` doesn't work in binary mode, so it will split characters above the 127 code point into two bytes when printed. This happens only when printing. You can check with

```
String.fromCharCode(147).length; // 1
```

If you are willing to write a file, you can use the fs module to write it in binary:

```
var a = new Uint8ClampedArray([37, 38, 39]),
    fs = require('fs');

var b = [].map.call(a, function(v){
    return String.fromCharCode(v);
}).join("");

fs.write("img.dat", b, "wb");
```

Comment: Ok, I've been able to pinpoint what does not work. The problem is that `String.fromCharCode()` outputs two bytes for values that are between 128 and 256. Any idea how I would go about it?

Comment: I don't see a way doing it with `console.log()`, but `fs.write()` works.

Comment: I see, thanks. Any way to write as binary using `system.stdout.write`? Or conversely, to write to `stdout` using the fs module? 

Otherwise my alternative (I can't write to actual files) will be to base64 encode on the fly then decode in the process I'm piping to (`ffmpeg`)

Comment: `system.stdout.write` also uses UTF-8 encoding. So, using an intermediate piped decoding application seems to be the only viable workaround.

Comment: Ok, I've been able to find a way to write to stdout using the fs module (see my answer). Thanks for your help!